# How to find all possible combinations in SQL table?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT `model` from `goods`
```

Shows me all unique values of model in a table

```
SELECT DISTINCT `submodel` from `goods`
```

Shows me all unique values of submodel in a table

How could I request all possible combinations of model-submodel which exist in this table?

Comment: can you give an example of all possible combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Model,submodel from goods group by model,submodel
```

Comment: you should add an explanation - code only answers are very low quality and seem better suited to a comment than an answer

Answer (score 3):

These two queries will give you two tables which each one has only a column. So you can just do something like this:

```
Select *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `model` from `goods`) as A, 
     (SELECT DISTINCT `submodel` from `goods`) as B
```

This will give you all possible combination of model-submodel in this table.

This type of join is also known as [CARTESIAN JOIN](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)